# Pulse audio driver malfunctioning?

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio

So I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit on a Eee Asus netbook, and occasionally when I use VLC media player this message displays freezing up the video along with:

```
Potential PulseAudio version problem:
PulseAudio is streaming with an excessive latency. Sound may be lost or quality degraded.
To address that issue, upgrade the PulseAudio daemon to version 3.0, or disable the alternate sampling rate in its configuration.
```

What should I do?

If i upgraded the driver, how do I upgrade it correctly?

Comment: Pulseaudio is the sound server and not a driver. To upgrade it, you'll need to use a newer release, say 13.04. You might also research that error first, as it might just be a VLC related bug. Any problems with pulseaudio with Totem or any other player?

Comment: No I haven't had any other issues with other players, only in VLC MP does it freeze up and say this. So all i really need to do if I want to fix this is update my OS? I called it a driver because thats what it said it was, by the way.